# When is entanglement entropy the same as free energy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, entropy, quantum-entanglement, ads-cft

I am given the feeling that there exists scenarios when this equality holds.
Can anyone state/refer to the situations?

---

One case that I hear of is that for $2+1$ CFTs the entanglement entropy across a spatial disk is the same as the free energy of the CFT system on a $S^2 \times S^1$ (or $S^3$?)

- What is the exact correct statement?
- I am told that this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0440 "proves" the above but despite reading this paper a few times I can't locate this argument! (...may be I am missing something very badly!...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is in the section 4.2 of the paper, with the claim being made in the last paragraph of that section. See also

> https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1548

Comment: Motl Thanks for your efforts! So you mean that 4.2 of my linked 1102.0440 proves this free energy equality?

Comment: Yes, wouldn't it be easier for both of us to look at the section than to ask again whether you should look?